# Typescript: export variables from js file just to consume types

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a javascript project, where i am using typescript as a helper, not planning to actually convert the whole project to typescript anytime soon.

In the `index` file, there are some variables defined, say `varA` and `varB`, which are populated in index file, but passed on as parameters when invoking functions in other files. I want to add types for these functions defined in other files. All these functions have the same interface. To do that, I am creating a type declaration file where i will define the common interface and use it as JSDoc in each individual function file. I don't want to manually define the type of `varA` and `varB` in the declaration file, but want to use the types automatically inferred in `index.js`. To do this, one way that i can see this working is if i explicitly export these variables and import them in the declaration file. This doesn't seem alright though, as i am only exporting the variables for types, they are not actually used in any other files directly. Are there better alternatives to doing this?

```
//index.js

const varA = getConfigVar(..., 'a');
const varB = getConfigVar(..., 'b');

//... do something
if(something) {
  funA(a, b);
} else {
  funB(a, b);
}

//?? just exporting for types
module.exports = {
  varA,
  varB,
}
```

```
// funA
/** @type {Func} **/
function funA(a, b) {
...
}
```

```
// funB
/** @type {Func} **/
function funB(a, b) {
...
}
```

```
//types.d.ts
interface Func {
    (a: typeof import('./index').a, b: typeof import('./index').b)): void
}
```

Comment: as mentioned, I do not plan to convert the whole project to ts because of multiple reasons. (Do not want to deal with the intricacies of ts compiler, do not want it to be a ts first codebase as multiple Devs would have a learning curve, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Define the types in their own files, even if it's just a `a.d.ts` file of

```js
import {a} from './index.js';

export type A = typeof a;
```

Your typescript code can then use this `A` type that is *currently* defined implicitly but you can change that if/when you're ready in exactly one place.

Comment: I don't get this. this would still require exporting the variable from index.js only for types?

Comment: You want the types automatically inferred from index.js, you have something that works, but it doesn't smell right to you. Is that correct? My suggestion is: Don't define it everywhere you use it, define it once, centrally, even if it's implicit. That way, you can change how you define it centrally instead of having to find every place you use it and change it there.

Comment: yeah, your understanding is correct. Yes, your suggestion is an improvement for better management of type (that's how I have defined it, in a global types.d.ts). That dos not answer the question though